UDEV don't name correctly network interfaces without rebooting
I'm trying to use the predictable system for interface naming with the (4) scheme.
My problem is that when I plug an USB Ethernet it always pick a name in ethX instead of enx{MAC} and I have to reboot the computer to have the accurate naming.
Does anybody have a lead for me, I am looking to understand why the name isn't properly calculated directly. My goal is to use the system on computer that we should not reboot.
Regards,
Nicolas
https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/
PS: after reboot if I unplug and replug the dongle, ethX come back :(

So ! I figured out my problem. On my Debian 12 connman seems to be faster to handle network interface so by disabling it, udev work as intended.
